# What is Ben Foster doing in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, hell-or-high-water

In the movie Hell Or High Water, what is Ben Foster's character doing to the girl in the scene at the casino?

To me, it seems like he is doing something nasty with the chip, pushing toward her body in some way but I can't be sure. The scene happens at around minute 39-40. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's doing exactly what it appears he is doing.

### Shoving a chip up her dress.

He accuses her of being a prostitute and as he pushes the chip upwards he comments..

> "Mind if I sample the goods!?"